# XCode fatal error can't open file list

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I'm new to coding with `xcode` and moved some files around and now getting an error.

Apple Mach-O Librarian Error
fatal error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file list file: FILENAMES (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried renaming things and cannot figure this out.I have been able to build the app but when I go into `Archive` to submit it always gives me this error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: check for any duplicates and remove it. "FILENAMES" contains what?

Comment: "FILENAMES" is the name of the app.  What do you mean for check for any duplicates.  Duplicates of what?

Comment: any imagenames like that